# Running as administrator apps block mouse clicks to regular app windows

Tags: windows-10, mouse, administrator, gui, non-admin

I am having this weird issue, where if an application is executed as admin, the OS GUI of regular ran apps no longer accepts mouse events.

Also, it is not a case of one foreground "admin" app blocking access to everything else. Only access to non-admin apps is blocked, I can have multiple different windows of apps, ran as admin and for those it works as expected.

Alt+tab does work switch away from the admin app, and at that point regular windows accept clicks as normal.

The taskbar and "OS gui" elements are also blocked - not just app windows.

I presume it is some "security feature" that got silently activated after a system update. How do I turn it off?

Comment: I very much doubt Windows is to blame. Do you use any unusual software like security software, WindowBlinds (or similar) or other software that deeply modifies the system? Is your Windows system modified otherwise (spy stuff removed or whatever)? Does this happen with all software that runs as admin? Also with Task Manager?

Comment: @DanielB I got o&o shutup10, but I don't see any setting about that in there,